# Whether css text-transform capitalize make other letters lowercase?

Tags: css

By definition, `text-transform: capitalize` capitalizes the first letter of each word in the selected text. But it only works for the lowercase text. My text is all uppercase, how can I use css `text-transform` to make the first letter uppercase and other letters lowercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`::first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) can be used to select the first letter from the first line of [block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model#Block-level_elements_and_block_boxes).

```css
p {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
p::first-letter {
  color: red;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<p class="capitalize">lowercase</p>
<p class="capitalize">UPPERCASE</p>
```

Comment: It's there a more direct way?